# Reproduce load average calculation

Tags: bash, kernel, load-average

I am digging into calculation of LA. So, what have I found:

1. LA calculates as exponential moving average every five seconds:

   ```
    LA(t) = LA(t-1) + EXP_R * (n(t) - LA(t-1))
   ```

   where

   - LA(t-1) - is the LA recorded on the previous iteration
   - EXP_R - are three predefined constants for 1, 5, and 15 minutes
   - n(t) - number of `R` (running) or `D` (uninterruptible) processes in the system
2. Here is the kernel code doing the stuff (and some magic with floating numbers as well):

   ```c
   unsigned long avenrun[3];

   static inline void calc_load(unsigned long ticks)
   {
       unsigned long active_tasks; /* fixed-point */
       static int count = LOAD_FREQ;

       count -= ticks;
       if (count < 0)
       {
           count += LOAD_FREQ;
           active_tasks = count_active_tasks();
           CALC_LOAD(avenrun[0], EXP_1, active_tasks);
           CALC_LOAD(avenrun[1], EXP_5, active_tasks);
           CALC_LOAD(avenrun[2], EXP_15, active_tasks);
       }
   }


   static unsigned long count_active_tasks(void)
   {
       struct task_struct *p;
       unsigned long nr = 0;

       read_lock(&tasklist_lock);
       for_each_task(p)
       {
           if ((p->state == TASK_RUNNING ||
                (p->state & TASK_UNINTERRUPTIBLE)))
               nr += FIXED_1;
       }
       read_unlock(&tasklist_lock);
       return nr;
   }


   #define FSHIFT          11              /* nr of bits of precision */
   #define FIXED_1         (1<<FSHIFT)     /* 1.0 as fixed-point */
   #define LOAD_FREQ       (5*HZ)          /* 5 sec intervals */
   #define EXP_1           1884            /* 1/exp(5sec/1min) as fixed-point */
   #define EXP_5           2014            /* 1/exp(5sec/5min) */
   #define EXP_15          2037            /* 1/exp(5sec/15min) */

   #define CALC_LOAD(load,exp,n) \
           load *= exp; \
           load += n*(FIXED_1-exp); \
           load >>= FSHIFT;
   ```
3. I've written naive bash script that tries to do the same stuff:

   ```bsh
   #!/usr/bin/env bash
   set -euo pipefail

   LA_1=0
   LA_5=0
   LA_15=0

   EXP_1=0.0800
   EXP_5=0.0165
   EXP_15=0.0055

   count() {
       echo $(ps -eostat | grep -E "R|D" | wc -l)
   }

   echo "1 min          5 min            15 min"

   while true; do
       n=$(($(count) - 1)) # -1 to eliminate `ps` from the result
       LA_1=$(bc -l  <<<"$LA_1  + $EXP_1  * ($n - $LA_1)")
       LA_5=$(bc -l  <<<"$LA_5  + $EXP_5  * ($n - $LA_5)")
       LA_15=$(bc -l <<<"$LA_15 + $EXP_15 * ($n - $LA_15)")
       echo -ne "$LA_1      $LA_5      $LA_15\r"
       sleep 5
   done
   ```

But the results of my script are far from the actual LA. I think that the main difference comes from the counting of active processes, where kernel calls `count_active_tasks()` and my script uses simple `ps`.

Can I somehow get the more precise number of active tasks from bash? Or maybe I am doing wrong somewhere else?

UPD: I was running my script for a while and here is the result:

```
1 min                      5 min                      15 min
.42342580723140551985      .53553677285166903835      .35305247755440928285
```

While actual LA is:

```
load average: 0.80, 1.63, 1.54
```

The kernel source code is taken from this article explaining LA: https://wiki.nix-pro.com/view/Load_average_explained

UPD: Definition of EXP_R in my script differs from the definition from the kernel source code: In my script it is actually 1 - exp_kernel (where exp_kernel - is the definition in the kernel source). It does not influence the final result because the final factor holds the same

Comment: I also think it can be because of the moments of time when my script and kernel do counting of processes are different, but on the other hand it should not influence much in long term.

Comment: NB: I subtract 1 from the count that `ps` gives because every time I run `ps` I see it in the running processes which is not fair I think

Comment: The calculations seem off - you have taken `l*e + n*(1-e)` and converted that to `l + (1-e)*(n-l)`. How did you derive this form?

Comment: @muru I think you are right, I've updated script and now it's quite accurate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank to @muru, he has found error in the formula I use. Here is the correct one and the results are pretty accurate:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -euo pipefail

LA_1=0
LA_5=0
LA_15=0

EXP_1=0.9200
EXP_5=0.9835
EXP_15=0.9945

count() {
    echo $(ps -eostat | grep -E "R|D" | wc -l)
}

echo "1 min         5 min           15 min"

while true; do
    n=$(($(count) - 1))
    LA_1=$(bc -l   <<<"$LA_1  * $EXP_1 +  $n * (1 - $EXP_1)")
    LA_5=$(bc -l   <<<"$LA_5  * $EXP_5 +  $n * (1 - $EXP_5)")
    LA_15=$(bc -l  <<<"$LA_15 * $EXP_15 + $n * (1 - $EXP_15)")
    echo -ne "$LA_1      $LA_5      $LA_15\r"
    sleep 5
done
```